# How to debug an application by using Visual Studio through the ssh-tunnel

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have:

1. Local windows 10 with VS2017
2. Remote Debian-1 with access from a local machine
3. Remote Debian-2 with access from a Debian-1 and .NET Core Console app

How to attach from local Windows 10 to Debian-2 by using ssh tunnel for debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

1. Set the following settings for the PuTTY tunnel. `Source port: 12345`, `Destination: localhost:12345`, `Local`, `Auto`
2. After establishing connection with Debian-1 execute the following command `ssh -L 12345:localhost:22 user@debian2`
3. In Visual Studio. Debug->Attach to process. Select connection type to ssh. Connection target localhost:12345